# What are estimated magnetic properties of liquid metallic hydrogen?

Tags: electromagnetism, hydrogen, jupiter

I understand that liquid metallic hydrogen isn't easy to produce, or keep it stable on Earth, but can be liquid metallic hydrogen magnetised? Does it have magnetic properties at all?

Comment: I presume that your last sentence should read "Does it have magnetic properties at all?" (since metallic hydrogen should indeed have metallic properties). A quick scan of a search on Web of Science shows a variety of articles on magnetic fields of gas giants and liquid metallic hydrogen, but no obvious work on magnetic properties of liquid metallic hydrogen.

Comment: Btw, does liquid metallic hydrogen considered as exotic matter?

Comment: @Ba-Lee - No, liquid metallic hydrogen is not exotic matter. It even has atoms!

Comment: I think it's unlikely that we know for sure given that we can’t at present make metallic H without breaking our diamonds... I see one 1986 article reporting a theoretical calculation stating that “a stable antiferromagnetic phase is obtained for metallic H” (PRB **33**, 324) if it helps, then a 1991 article cites it stating that it “undergoes a second transition from a ferromagnetic metal to a ferromagnetic insulator.” (PRB **43**, 825), hunting down citations might get you our best guesses, but those might assume a solid form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to expect metallic hydrogen to be any more magnetic than say metallic sodium, that is, patamagnetic. One caveat is that at sufficiently high pressure and low temperature it may become superconducting.
Apparently, rotating liquid sodium will generate a magnetic field as this experiment aims to prove : https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=OsPyQ4Sv-DA&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Do you think that "Na" would generate magnetic field around a planet, if it would be in a center of, for example a gas giant?

Comment: Liquid paramagnetic metal will generate a magnetic field if it rotates.

Comment: Cool! Has it been any experiments about this?

Comment: I added a link to my answer that will interest you.